# Convergenge of sequence in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence

During this COVID outbreak I am tutoring some students from my university with their courses as they are overwhelmed with their online assignments. However, I studied Physics and to be honest I have forgotten an important part of the theorems from the calculus/analysis courses that I myself undertook more than 4 years ago. In particular, one of the students needs help answering the following exercise:

Determine if the following sequence in $\mathbb{R}^3$ converges. If that is the case, find the corresponding limit:

$$\{\bar{x}_k\}=\left\{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}, \sum_{i=1}^k \left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^i , \int_1^{1+\frac{1}{k}}\frac{dt}{t}\right) \right\},$$

which
 can be rewritten as

$$\{\bar{x}_k\}=\left\{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}, \sum_{i=1}^k \left(1+\frac{1}{i}\right)^i , \log\left({1+\frac{1}{k}}\right)\right) \right\}.$$

Its obvious that the third entry converges to 0. Moreover, I implemented the sequence numerically and it seems that the only entry that does not converge is the second one, but how can I state this formally? I remember about the different convergence criteria but I don't know which one to use in this case. Any help or explanation will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. If $a_n \ge 1$ for infinitely many $n$, then the sum diverges since, if $b_n$ is a sequence containing all of the $a_n$ that are at least $1$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \ge \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1 = \infty$$

Here, $a_n = (1 + 1/n)^n$. Since $n \ge 1$, then $1/n > 0$; thus, $1+1/n > 1$, and $(1+1/n)^n > 1$ as well, so the divergence is obvious. In fact, $a_n$ is a monotonic increasing sequence which converges to $e$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!.

Answer (score 0):

The first one converges, as it's an alternating series with the term $1/i$ positive, decreases, and converges to $0$.

For the second one, note that $\lim_{i\to \infty} (1+1/i)^i = e^1=e$. Hence, the terms in the sum don't converge to $0$. By the divergence test, the sum diverges.